# network.service - after executing "telinit" network interfaces doesn't start

Tags: networking, rhel

When I start RHEL 7 everything is fine, my network functions, I can ping other PC's etc:

```
[root@localhost]# service network status
Configured devices:
lo eno1 enp2s0f0Team enp2s0f1Team team0 team0.300 team0.398 team0.399
Currently active devices:
lo eno1 enp2s0f0 enp2s0f1 team0 team0.300@team0 team0.398@team0 team0.399@team0
```

But if I execute `telinit 3` to switch to command-line interface, network disappear:

```
[root@localhost]# service network status
Configured devices:
lo eno1 enp2s0f0Team enp2s0f1Team team0 team0.300 team0.398 team0.399
Currently active devices:
lo eno1
```

I lost LACP+VLAN card, only one card is left - eno1. `ifconfig` missing these interfaces too as they just doesn't exist.
I guess this is network.service issue (more likely) or may be teaming issue.

Workaround: after telinit 3 I have to execute `service network stop` and `service network start` to make network working.

I faced this problem when I've disabled NetworkManager in favor of network.service.

How can I fix my problem? `network.service` is not configured well?